# If $f$ is continuous and real valued and $f'$ integrable on $[a, b],$ and $\int_a^b f' = f(b) - f(a)$, must $f$ be absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Here is a question I had as I read about absolutely continuous functions. If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and real valued, $f'$
integrable on $[a, b],$ and $\int_a^b f' = f(b) - f(a)$, must $f$ be absolutely continuous? What if $f$ is monotone increasing as opposed to continuous?

Intuitively I would think yes to my first question and no to my second but I am not sure. My intuition say yes to the first question since there is a theorem in Royden that tells us that a function $f$ on a closed, bounded interval $[a, b]$ is
absolutely continuous on $[a, b]$ if and only if it is an indefinite integral over
$[a, b].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your intuition:  The identity $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(t)\,dt$ does *not* say that $f$ is an *indefinite integral*.  For that you would require instead that $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(t)\,dt$ for all $x$.

**COMMENTS:**

You don't specify but here is the **everywhere** case that perhaps you intended.

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is *everywhere* differentiable (so of course it is continuous).  Then the following is well-known (one hopes):

1. If $f'$ is Riemann integrable then $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(x)\,dx$ in the sense of the Riemann integral. [But a derivative does not have to be Riemann integrable.]
2. If $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(x)\,dx$ in the sense of the Lebesgue integral. [But a derivative does not have to be  Lebesgue integrable.]
3. In general $f'$ must be Denjoy-Perron integrable and $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(x)\,dx$ in the sense of that integral.

Maybe you are interested instead in the case where $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is *almost* *everywhere* differentiable.  There are some tidbits that one should know:

a. There are nonconstant continuous functions that have a derivative equal to zero almost everywhere.

b. Therefore two different continuous functions can have the same a.e. derivative.

c.  Given *any* measurable function $g$ there is a continuous function $f$ so that $f'=g$ almost everywhere.

**Ex.**  Take a continuous function $f$ so that $f(0)=0$, $f(\frac12)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ but with $f'(x)=0$ a.e..  Then
$$ 0 = f(1)-f(0) = \int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx = 0 $$
in the sense of the Lebesgue integral and this meets your conditions for a function that is not absolutely continuous.

Your other question is about continuous monotone functions.  If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous, monotone nondecreasing function then (you will recall) the $f'$ exists a.e. and is Lebesgue integrable.  Moreover
$$ \int_a^b f'(x)\,dx \leq f(b)-f(a). \tag{1}$$
You might think that you get strict inequality when $f$ is not absolutely continuous and you get equality only in the case where $f$ is absolutely continuous.

There is a better version of (1) that makes this clearer.  Instead of the inequality (1) we can write instead:

$$ f(b)-f(a) =  \int_a^b f'(x)\,dx + \lambda_f(D_\infty). \tag{2}$$

Here $\lambda_f$ is the Lebesgue-Steiltjes measure associated with $f$ and $D_\infty$ is the set of points in $[a,b]$ where $f'(x)=+\infty$.  The second term is zero if and only if $f$ is absolutely continuous.  [This is a theorem of the Belgian mathematician de la Vallée Poussin.]  So that is an answer to your second question.

[Dinner time so a bit rushed.  If you need references I can find some.]

Comment: I may have to take you up on those references in your free time. But for now thank you for giving me something to chew on.

Comment: B.S. Thomson, this might be an obvious question but why in the example you gave can we conclude that $f$ is not absolutely continuous?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen  This is the easy one.  There is a singular function (continuous, derivative a.e. equal to zero) with $f(0)=f(1)=0$, but not constant.  [If it were absolutely continuous it would have to be constant.]